# Semistable filtered vector spaces, a Tannakian category.

Tags: tannakian-category, hodge-theory, filtrations

Let $k$ be a field (char = 0, perhaps).  Let $(V,F)$ be a pair, where $V$ is a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space, and $F$ is a filtration of $V$, indexed by rational numbers, satisfying:

1. $F^i V \supset F^j V$ when $i < j$.
2. $F^i V = V$ for $i << 0$.  $F^i V = \{ 0 \}$ for $i >> 0$.
3. $F^i V = \bigcap_{j < i} F^j V$.

We define:
$$F^{i+} V = \bigcup_{j > i} F^j V.$$

The slope of $(V,F)$ (when $V \neq \{ 0 \}$) is the rational number:
$$M(V,F) = \frac{1}{dim(V)} \sum_{i \in Q} i \cdot dim(F^i V / F^{i+} V).$$

The pair $(V,F)$ is called semistable if $M(W, F_W) \leq M(V, F)$ for every subspace $W \subset V$, with the subspace filtration $F_W$.

A paper of Faltings and Wustholz constructs an additive category with tensor products, whose objects are semistable pairs $(V,F)$.  A paper of Fujimori, "On Systems of Linear Inequalities", Bull. Soc. Math. France, seems to imply that the full subcategory of slope-zero objects (together with the zero object) is Tannakian (the abelian category axioms require semistability), with fibre functor to the category of $k$-vector spaces (though Fujimori considers quite a bit more).

Does anyone know another good reference for the properties of this Tannakian category?  Can you describe the associated affine group scheme over $k$?  I'm particularly interested, when $k$ is a finite field or a local field.

Update:  I think the slope-zero requirement is too strong (though it is assumed in Fujimori).  It seems to exclude almost all the semistable pairs $(V,F)$, if my linear algebra is correct.  Anyone want to explain this to me too?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you are still interested in this, one year later.

Check out the papers by Yves Andre (see [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.1553) and [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.3921)) as well as the articles of Burt Totaro and Laurent Fargues listed in the second.

Comment: Not too late at all.  Thank you very much!  I'll check out the articles you mention.

Comment: Theorem 0.7 in the first paper linked above (of Andre) seems to be what you are looking for.